# I have same url but ActionResult is different how can i handled it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have one problem in asp.net MVC4 like this 
i have url routing like when i search computer then my url is

```
www.aaaaa.com/computer-Company/computer/1
```

so i need to write code in RoutConfig.cs file please see the below code this is for index ActionResult

```
  routes.MapRoute(
     name: "CompanySearch",
     url: "{name}-Company/{TagName}/{page}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Company", action ="indix",Name = "", TagName = "", page = "" });
```

And Another ActionResult like Search like this

```
routes.MapRoute(
     name: "SearchCompany",
     url: "{name}-Company/{TagName}/{page}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Company", action ="Search",Name = "", TagName = "", page = "" });
```

And my problem is When i try to redirect to Search method in company controller it automatically redirect to index because of routing problem when i remove this code it will work but not proper routing please solve my problem

Comment: You missspelled Index

Comment: You have two same routes. You cannot handle two different actions.

Comment: it may be due to the fact that you are using the same url pattern for both 'companysearch' and 'searchCompany'. Framework will check the url patterns in the same order that are added, once there is a match it wont check for the remaining routes. (Experts, please correct me if I am wrong)

Comment: how can i solve it here my index method is before login and my search method is after login